# Postgresql: COPY FROM csv file with occational missing columns

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse, etl

I have several billion rows of data in CSV files. Each row can have anything from 10 to 20 columns. I want to use COPY FROM to load the data into a table containing 20 columns. If a specific CSV row only contains 10 columns of data, then I expect COPY FROM to set the rest of the columns (for which the values are missing) to NULL. I specify DEFAULT NULL on every column in the CREATE TABLE statement.

**MY QUESTION:**
Can this be done using COPY FROM?

EDIT: Greenplum (a database based upon PostgreSQL) has a switch named FILL MISSING FIELDS, which does what I describe (see their documentation [here](http://www.greenplum.com/docs/3300/sql-copy.html)). What workarounds would you recommend for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a pre-processing script to just add some extra commas on the lines that don't have enough columns, or to transform the CSV into TSV (tab-separated) and put "\N" in the extra columns.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make COPY FROM deal with different number of columns inside the same file.

If it's *always* the same 10 columns that are missing, a workaround could be to first load everything into a staging table that has a single `text` column.

After that, you can use SQL to split the line and extract the columns, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, ...)
SELECT columns[1], columns[2], ...
FROM ( 
  SELECT string_to_array(big_column, ',') as columns
    FROM staging_table 
) t
WHERE array_length(columns) = 10
```

and then do a similar thing with `array_length(columns) = 20`

Comment: This seems like a way to do this, but I am concerned about the performance as all data needs to be inserted into two tables.

Comment: I don't see a different way, unless you can change the creation process of the CSV files

Answer (score 1):

In a context of `etl` and `data-warehouse` -- my suggestion would be to actually avoid the "shortcut" you are looking for.

ETL is a process, frequently implemented as ECCD (Extract, Clean, Conform, Deliver). You could treat those files as "Extracted", so simply implement data cleaning and conforming as different steps -- you will need some extra disk space for that. All conformed files should have the "final" (all columns) structure. Then deliver (`COPY FROM`) those conformed files.

This way you will also be able to document the ETL process and what happens to the missing fields in each step.

It is a usual practice to archive (disk, DVD) original customer files and conformed versions for audit and debug purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was feeling down to actually have to go that one step more, but after reading this it seems the proper way to go anyhow : )

Answer (score 0):

From the [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html):

> COPY FROM will raise an error if any
>   line of the input file contains more
>   or fewer columns than are expected.

Read the first line of your CSV file to see how many columns you have to name in the COPY statement.

Comment: Write a script which will pre-process files eg check number of delimiters in some are missing add them. If you like writing scritps